# Why do colored solutions become more transparent as volume is decreased?

Tags: concentration, color, spectrophotometry

For instance, I was drinking Gatorade, and as I drank more and more, the drink became lighter in color. Why?
I don't understand. I would think that the molarity stays constant and the color too.

I feel like it's a really basic question, but as finals approach, I seem to have forgotten everything I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [Beer - Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) in action. The color you see depends on absorbance, which is proportional to molarity **and** the thickness of your specimen.

Come to think of it, how could it be otherwise? Would you expect 1cm thick layer of liquid to look the same as 10cm? What about 1mm? Or 0.1mm?